# Alloweditusers function failing

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function that removes the allow edit range from Excel, but I keep on getting an error `indicating that method delete of object alloweditrange failed`

```
Sub RemoveUserEditRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, aer As AllowEditRange
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protection")
    ws.Unprotect
    For Each aer In ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges
        aer.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting your sheet before the loop :

```
ws.Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have that range?

Try this

```
Sub RemoveUserEditRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protection")

    With ws
        .Unprotect
        With .Protection
            If .AllowEditRanges.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Nothing to delete"
            Else
                '~~> Check if there is actually a range
                Do While .AllowEditRanges.Count > 0
                    .AllowEditRanges(1).Delete
                Loop
            End If
        End With
        .Protect '<~~ ???
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: indeed, that code worked. I suppose I fixed my challenge by activating the sheet. In essence the workbook was on a different sheet and when I reactivated the sheet before running the code. The problem went away. Funny that the sheet needs to be activated, quite unusual.